# Approximating an integral with rectangles? Legal?

Tags: calculus, integration

I've come across this while navigating on $\text{WiKiPeDiA}$:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i)\Delta_i$ Basically we can illustrate that as:

[image]

This means that we approximate curved functions with rectangles, same approach done by Leibiniz to introduce the concept of integral. But I'm asking, is it legal? I mean we are just approximating it, if we draw rectangles till infinity then we wouldn't have the exact answer because the graph is curved, it is not smooth. This approach reminds me of the famous "Proof Pi=4"

[image]
Will we know that it is wrong and that Pi=3.14... Is the same for calculus, and why?

In response to some comments, let $C$ be a circle of radius $r$, we can divide (as in the picture) into 4. You get it if you see the picture

[image]

Comment: Area is much better behaved than arclength.

Comment: But that's still an approximation @AndréNicolas

Comment: Area is much behaved than the curved circle too, we get a false result.

Comment: You have to be careful any time you say "repeat to infinity".  You're implying some form of convergence, and in your second example, the rectangular approximations are not actually converging to the circle in the "correct" sense.

Comment: Part of the arclength problem occurs due to assuming that a set of $90^\circ$ turns can correctly approximate a smooth curve.  For area, did you actually calculate the area of a circle using removed squares? It should get pretty close.  And while using a finite set of rectangles is an approximation, taking the limit as our number of rectangles increases (assuming the intermediate steps are actually approaching the correct value) causes the approximation to reach an exact value.

Comment: Well, the rectangles used to approximate the graph are getting more and more jagged - not smoother.

Comment: The answers haven't really addressed your question.  Basically, the right answer is that the limit of the sum of rectangles _doesn't_ always give you the correct value.  It does when you make the right assumptions—as approximating arclength also works when you make the right assumptions.

It turns out that any continuous function is well-behaved enough to give a good result when you apply the Riemann integral.  But it's a useful exercise to try constructing examples where the sums don't converge, or the value depends on which rectangles you use, etc.  Lebesgue integrals help somewhat.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This is "legal" for continuous curves.

The heart of the issue is whether your approximation is actually converging to the object in question or not.

For area under a curve, one can show that the Riemann sums (sums of areas of rectangles) better and better approximate the area under the curve as the number of rectangles increases. Thus -- Voila! -- the limit gives us the area under the curve (in fact we may *define* area in this way).

On the other hand, the $\pi=4$ false proof tricks you into thinking the approximation is approaching the circle when it really isn't -- or at least its arc length isn't.

The curve you are using to approximate the circle is getting more and more jagged - not smoother and smoother. This kind of indicates that it's a poor approximation of a circle.

Or from a another viewpoint, the square containing the circle gives an overestimate for the circumference. Similarly one could inscribe a square (or diamond) and get an underestimate of $2\sqrt{2}$. As you continue to "flip corners over" the estimates remain constant revealing that your "approximations" aren't going anywhere.

You must be careful anytime you send things off to infinity. Finitely many steps don't necessarily predict the ultimate outcome.

Edit: More on why Riemann sums converge to the area...

This can be better seen using [Darboux integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral). Darboux uses a set of rectangles that over-estimate the area and then a second set of rectangles that under-estimate the area. As we use more and more rectangles, the upper bound keeps on creeping down and the lower bound keeps on creeping up. For nice enough functions (such as continuous functions) these two numbers approach each other. So these approximations are getting better and better as the number of rectangles increases.

In addition one can prove that any choice of rectangles (as long as their widths are heading to zero) will tend to this same number (mostly because it's squeezed between these bounds).

For the squaring the circle $\pi=4$ false proof the estimate never gets better.

Comment: Well, the rectangles used to approximate the graph are getting more and more jagged - not smoother.

Comment: See my comment in top

Comment: It might help to add that the reason it makes sense to _define_ area as the limit of Riemann sums is that (1) this limit exists, and (2) the limit does not depend on the choice of approximating rectangles, only that their maximum width approaches zero.  (And moreover, both (1) and (2) can fail for arc length.)

Comment: So how we perfectly calculate arc graph integrals?

Comment: @FuturePhdInMathematics What do you mean by arc graph integrals?

Comment: About being jagged, sure. I didn't say that that's *the* reason why it doesn't converge. This is just an indication. As for arc length,  one approximates arc length of a curve using lengths of line segments much in the same way rectangles are used to approximate areas. This can be shown (for functions with continuous first derivative) to converge to a number which we call arc length.

Comment: The exact integral of a cuved graph.

Comment: One can approximate the circumference of a circle by inscribing regular polygons (triangle, square, pentagon...) and calculating their perimeters. This process does converge to the circumference of the circle.

Comment: It converges but it doesn't give us the exact value since as the width of the polygons gets close to 0 we still have non-smooth approximation.

Comment: Any particular approximation is not exact for sure, but they continue to get better and the *limit* of their perimeters is exact.

Comment: @BillCook They continue to get better but if you zoom in you will see no "exact non-smooth approximation". Also: *Darboux integrals are equivalent to Riemann integrals, meaning that a function is Darboux-integrable if and only if it is Riemann-integrable, and the values of the two integrals, if they exist, are equal. *

Comment: Well sure, the curve itself isn't ever going to "become" a circle. The point is that the arc length of the polygons is approaching  the arc length of the circle. Smaller and smaller line segments allow for smaller and smaller errors coming from the difference between an arc and a line. Also, the definition of a Darboux integral is not the same as a Riemann integral. However, yes, they give the same answers for Riemann integrable functions. Darboux and Riemann *compute* the same thing just in slightly different ways.

Comment: But even with that there is an error in the calculation, it is not perfect.

Comment: At any individual step there is error, but in the limit there is not. You might want to read some about limits, get a good grasp of how they actually work and then come back to this issue. As you limit, you are never working at the actual point just "close" to it. The idea is "getting close" (while potentially not ever actually "being there").

Comment: I have to ask, your "Viola!", is it intentional, or is it a misspelled "voilà!"?

Comment: Now I kind of like "Viola!" better - but no. It was not on purpose - I wish it was.

Answer (score 1):

The question is getting rather broad, but let's see if I can answer a part of it.

One answer to the question of why the area under a continuous function is a limit of Riemann sums is that we *define* it that way.  But for that to make sense, we need the see that the limit *exists*, and also that this definition corresponds with our physical intuitions about area.

To see this informally, notice that any lower Riemann sum (*e.g.* the area of the red region) gives an underestimate of the area under the curve, and similarly an upper Riemann sum (*e.g.* the area of the green region) gives an overestimate.  This is just using the intuitive fact that the area of a subset is at most the area of the entire set.

(Here we are using a signed notion of "area" in which areas below the $x$-axis count as negative.)

Therefore the true area, if such a thing exists, must be at least the value of any lower Riemann sum and at most the value of any upper Riemann sum. 
That is, an upper sum gives an upper bound and a lower sum gives a lower bound.
Considering any pair consisting of a lower sum and upper sum, *e.g.* red and green above, does not pin down the true area entirely, but only gives us some "approximation interval" in which it must lie if it exists.

By using thinner rectangles in our upper and lower sums, we can get a smaller upper bound and a larger lower bound, therefore giving us a smaller approximation interval.  In fact, by using sufficiently thin rectangles we can make this interval as small as desired.  (This is not entirely obvious, and you shoudn't take my word for it, but perhaps consult an analysis textbook instead.)
This is the step where we use continuity of the function, and indeed if it were not continuous then all of the upper sums could be much larger than all of the lower sums, so that our "approximations" are not approximating anything in particular.

Now the notion of limit comes in.  Because the length of the approximation intervals is approaching zero as the width of the rectangles approaches zero, the completeness property of the real numbers implies that there is a (unique) real number that is contained in all of the approximation intervals—that is, it is above all the lower bounds given by lower Riemann sums and below all the upper bounds given by upper Riemann sums.  The true area under the curve is defined to be (and intuitively must be) this number.

---

Why doesn't a similar argument work for arc length, you might ask?

Well, the reason is just that there isn't a similar argument for arc length.  If you try to make a similar argument, then I will try to refute it. In the meantime all I can say is that the particular argument of the comic doesn't work, because there is no reason to think that the "approximations" are good approximations to anything at any step.  Indeed, if we accept the notion of true arc length in this case as being given by the geometric formula for circumference of a circle, then they are all equally bad approximations.
Taking the limit of equally bad approximations, we still get an equally bad approximation in the limit.

Comment: I will comment on this later. Nice discussion anyway.

Comment: @FuturePhdInMathematics Thanks, I will try to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have sufficient knowledge, I didn't even star calculus I. All what I know is purely non abstract... So I will respond when I start and finish and develop my Calculus I and II skills.

Comment: @FuturePhdInMathematics Sounds like a good plan.  Once you become familiar with the definition of "limit" then you will have a better understanding of what approximation means in math.